# Using Build Manager Class to Load ASPX Files and Populate its Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms

I am using BuildManager Class to Load a dynamically generated ASPX File, please note that it does not have a corresponding .cs file.

Using Following code I am able to load the aspx file, I am even able to loop through the control collection of the dynamically created aspx file, but when I am assigning values to controls they are not showing it up. for example if I am binding the value "Dummy" to TextBox control of the aspx page, the textbox remains empty.

Here's the code that I am using

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadPage("~/Demo.aspx");
    }
    public static void LoadPage(string pagePath)
    {
        // get the compiled type of referenced path
        Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(pagePath);


        // if type is null, could not determine page type
        if (type == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Page " + pagePath + " not found");

        // cast page object (could also cast an interface instance as well)
        // in this example, ASP220Page is a custom base page
        System.Web.UI.Page pageView = (System.Web.UI.Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // call page title
        pageView.Title = "Dynamically loaded page...";

        // call custom property of ASP220Page
        //pageView.InternalControls.Add(
        //    new LiteralControl("Served dynamically..."));

        // process the request with updated object
        ((IHttpHandler)pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
        LoadDataInDynamicPage(pageView);

    }
    private static void LoadDataInDynamicPage(Page prvPage)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in prvPage.Controls)
        {
            //Find Form Control
            if (ctrl.ID != null)
            {
                if (ctrl.ID.Equals("form1"))
                {
                    AllFormsClass cls = new AllFormsClass();
                    DataSet ds = cls.GetConditionalData("1");
                    foreach (Control ctr in ctrl.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ctr is TextBox)
                        {
                            if (ctr.ID.Contains("_M"))
                            {

                                TextBox drpControl = (TextBox)ctr;
                                drpControl.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][ctr.ID].ToString();
                            }
                            else if (ctr.ID.Contains("_O"))
                            {

                                TextBox drpControl = (TextBox)ctr;
                                drpControl.Text = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][ctr.ID].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I saw that you got part of your code from [How To Dynamically Load A Page For Processing](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/07/06/how-to-dynamically-load-a-page-for-processing.aspx). Read the comments too as this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/07/06/how-to-dynamically-load-a-page-for-processing.aspx#3537049) by Mike.

Invert this:

```
((IHttpHandler)pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
LoadDataInDynamicPage(pageView);
```

To this:

```
LoadDataInDynamicPage(pageView);
((IHttpHandler)pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

In this case changing the order of the calls does change the end result I think. The inverse of [Commutativity property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity). :)